# Laravel 2 routes return different pages,with and without parameters

Tags: laravel, routes

I need to have 2 routes :

1)localhost/static1/{param1}/{param2}

and

2)localhost/static1/static2/{param3}

Static1 is the same in first and second url. My problem is that if i navigate to the second url, laravel will take static2 as param1 (param1 = static2) .How can i define these routes to make them return different pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the more strict route higher priority in your routes file, as below:

```
Route::get('static1/static2/{param3}', function(){});

Route::get ('static1/{param1}/{param2}', function(){});
```